# How to Implement URL Routing in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, standards, url-routing

How to implement URL Routing in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing. 

Try looking at that question.

Comment: In fact, possible triplicate =)

Comment: Either they're working together or it's a sock puppet account.

Comment: watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byjMGftJeyU

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use Apache you can do the URL routing via mod_rewrite.

Small example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(dir1)/?(path2)? main.php?dir=$1&path=$2
```

That'll have any request like

```
http://yoursite.com/dir1/path1
```

served by

```
http://yoursite.com/main.php?dir=dir1&path=path2
```

More examples [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Rewrite/).

The other alternative have every request redirect to a single php file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) main.php?request=$1
```

and then to do it in code, where you can use a [similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing), by having a set of regular expressions that are matched by some code and then redirected via header() or just internally.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you will need Apache's *(I suppose your webserver is Apache)* [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to be enabled.

Then, you need to create a RewriteRule to redirect everything to your index.php page.

Something like this could do :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

It will redirect every request to a file that doesn't exist to index.php ; this means that, if the requested URL is www.example.com/blah, it is actually index.php that will be called.

About that, here a couple of link that can help :

- [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
- [mod_rewrite: A Beginner's Guide to URL Rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/)

Then, this page has to determine what has to be displayed, depending on what initial URL was called -- or what parameters are received.

This can be done using the [Design Pattern Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), for instance -- it's implemented in most modern PHP Frameworks, for instance.

There have been many questions of this subject on SO ; some of those (and their answers) might probably help you. For instance :

- [How do I do URL rewriting in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522452/how-do-i-do-url-rewriting-in-php)
- [URL mapping in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395650/url-mapping-in-php)
- [PHP Application URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125677/php-application-url-routing)

Comment: This should be the standard answer to this question. It works for any server-side language running on Apache, and piles of rewrite rules are not particularly sustainable anyway.