# How do i grab value from url like http://.....com/value

Tags: php, url, member

I am developing an web application using php.
One of the requirement is the want member id looks like folder name such as
http......com//joe
The id is "joe"

Normally i will use http......com/?id=joe but my client don't what this idea...

How do i grab that id???

Thanks

Comment: I don't know PHP but in .net that type is used in the MVC framework using Http Routing.  Might want to look into PHP's routing capabilities?

Comment: mod_rewrite
read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522452/how-do-i-do-url-rewriting-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting).

With Apache, you are able to setup URL Rewriting for your PHP pages with mod_rewrite, check the following resources:

- [mod_rewrite: A Beginner's Guide to URL Rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting/)
- [Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
- [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)